# Writing from Device to Host and notifying the host

Tags: cuda

Using CUDA 5 with VS 2012 and capability 3.5 (Titan and K20).

At particular stages of my kernel execution, I want to send a generated data chunk to the host memory and notify the host that the data is ready, so the host will operate on it.

I cannot wait until the end of the kernel execution to read the data back from the device, because:

1. The data is no longer relevant to the device once it is calculated, so there is no point keeping it to the end.
2. The data size is too large to fit on the device memory and wait until the end.
3. The host should not have to wait until the end of the kernel execution to start processing the data.

> Could you point me to the path I have to take and the possible cuda concepts and functions I have to use to achieve my requirements? Put simply, how can I write to the host and notify the host that a chunk data is ready for host processing?

N.B. Each thread does not share any generated data with any other thread, they run independently. So, as far as I know (and please correct me if I am wrong), the concept of blocks, threads and warps do not affect the question. Or in other words, if they aid the answer, I am free to alter their combination.

Below is a sample code that shows that I am trying to do:

```c
#pragma once
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__global__ void Kernel(size_t length, float* hResult) 
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    // Processing multiple data chunks
    for(int i = 0;i < length;i++)
    {
        // Once this is assigned, I don't need it on the device anymore.
        hResult[i + (tid * length)] = i * 100;
    }

}

void main()
{
    size_t length = 10;
    size_t threads = 2;
    float* hResult;
    // An array that will hold all data from all threads
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&hResult, threads * length * sizeof(float));
    Kernel<<<threads,1>>>(length, hResult);
    // I DO NOT want to wait to the end and block to get the data
    cudaError_t error = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) { throw error; }
    for(int i = 0;i < threads * length;i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", hResult[i]);;
    }
    cudaFreeHost(hResult);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: How and when are the chunks of data generated? Does a couple of blocks generate one chunk? Or is each chunk made of data from all blocks, written at different times during the block's execution? In the latter case, you need to be aware that the generation of data is spread over the entire runtime of the kernel.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible approach.  At a high level, on the device:

- You'll need to write the data to either device global memory (allocated previously with `cudaMalloc`) or else directly to host memory (allocated previously with `cudaHostAlloc`).  This memory should be accessed via a `volatile` pointer.
- You may wish to do all the data writing to this region from a single threadblock, to be sure that all the data is written prior to the following steps
- You'll then want to issue a `threadfence()` (if you're using device global memory) or `threadfence_system()` call (if using host memory) prior to the following steps
- Next you'll write to a special location in device global memory or host memory, let's call it the mailbox location, with a specific value indicating the data is ready.  This location should also be accessed with a `volatile` pointer.
- Optionally issue another threadfence or threadfence_system call
- for device memory usage on the receiving end, again both regions (payload and "mailbox") should be accessed using a `volatile` pointer.

On the host:

- Before launching the kernel, the host will need to set the mailbox location to a default value.
- After launching the kernel, the host thread will need to "poll" the mailbox location, looking for the specific value indicating data is ready
- Once the specific value is seen, indicating that the data is ready, the host can consume the data
- Optionally, if you want to repeat this process, the host can reset the mailbox location to the default value.  The device can check for this default value before updating the data block with new data.
- Both the mailbox location and the payload region should be accessed by the host thread using a `volatile` pointer.

Note that even with the above process, there is still an implied device-wide synchronization needed, if the data is being generated/created from multiple threadblocks.  The only straightforward device-wide synchronization available is the kernel launch (or completion of the kernel, specifically).  Copying the data from a single threadblock simply moves the requirement for device-wide sync out of this particular sequence (to somewhere before this sequence).

The reasons you give don't really suggest to me that the code could not be refactored to create the data on a kernel-launch by kernel-launch basis, which would neatly solve these issues and eliminate the need for the above process as well.

**EDIT:** responding to a question in the comments.
It's difficult to be more specific about how to refactor the code to deliver one data chunk per kernel call, without a specific example.

Let's take an image processing case, where I have a video sequence of 30 frames stored in global memory.  The kernel will process each frame according to some algorithm, then make the processed data available to the host.

In your proposal, after the kernel is done processing a frame, it can signal to the host that the data is ready, and go on to process the next frame.  The problem is, if the frame is processed by multiple threadblocks, there's no easy way to know when all threadblocks are done processing that frame.  A device-wide synchronization barrier might be what is needed, but it doesn't exist conveniently, except via the kernel call mechanism.  However, presumably inside such a kernel we might have a sequence like this:

- while (more_frames)
- - process a frame
- - signal host
- - increment frame pointer

In a refactored approach, we would move the loop outside the kernel, to host code:

- while (more_frames)
- - call kernel to process frame
- - consume frame
- - increment frame pointer

By doing this, the kernel marks the explicit synchronization needed to know when the frame processing is complete, and the data can be consumed.

Comment: "refactored to create the data on a kernel-launch by kernel-launch basis" Could you elaborate on this one please? This process is vital in my code and I am happy to refactor if needed in the ideal way to support this scenario.
I have added a sample code based on the first part of your suggestion.

Comment: luckily, I have zero dependency between threads, so that should make it easier and doesn't require synchronization. (sample code added to the question).
I understand your poll suggestion, that is an async host loop trying to spot if a certain flag has changed then read the data if it did. right?

Comment: Yes, the mailbox is a flag that indicates to an async host loop that data is ready.  It's not a question of data dependency between threads.  It's a question of knowing when a thread (or block, etc. ) has processed a certain amount of data, so that it is consumable by the host.  You could keep a flag on a per block or per-thread basis, but that seems quite involved.  By the way, launching blocks of 1 thread each is leaving about 97% of the machine capability unused.